# ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click Restart

Tags: android

I am new to android studio, as i run android studio, this error is poped out.can anyone help me out with this error

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo adb devices`  - it restart youre adb.
if you have 64 bit Ubuntu more than 13 version, try install lid32ia like this `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6`